# Can I prevent Kivy from registering all VNC clicks as double clicks?

Tags: vnc

I'm using VNC to connect to a Raspberry Pi in order to run a Kivy project, which is run via Pycharm and SSH. The project is intended to run on a touchscreen connected to the Pi, but for the sake of testing I'm trying to interact with the GUI through a mouse with VNC.

I've enabled direct capture and relative pointer motion on VNC, and set cursor=1 under module so the GUI does register clicks and the mouse.

The program has a password screen, and all clicks on the password screen register as double clicks so I cannot type the password properly.

So far, I've tried changing the double click delay on the Raspberry Pi to both 100 and 1990, and changing min_state_time in .kivy/config.ini to be a 5+ digit number, and neither have worked. I've also checked (Via cookie clicker) and confirmed that the double click problem only happens in Kivy.

Is there any way to stop Kivy from double clicking on every click, or to disable double clicking entirely?